# how to remove class from html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So i am trying to detect if one of my navigational elements has a certain class upon click and if it does then remove it and if it don't then add it.

The methodology behind this is to show an active state on the dropdown button while the dropdown is open. And to loose that state once another nav element has been clicked or something outside the dropdown menu has been clicked. This logic currently works fine.

However another case i have is to loose the active state if the same button has been clicked, this currently dont work. The first condition in the if statement is never hit so the class is always being toggled.

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    //WORKS
    $(document).click(function () {
        $('.link.activeLink').removeClass('activeLink')
    });

    //WORKS
    $('.nav-link').click(function () {
        $('.link.activeLink').removeClass('activeLink')
    });

    //FAILS
    $('.link').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('activeLink')) {
            $(this).removeClass('activeLink');
        }
        else {
            $(this).toggleClass('activeLink');
        }
    }); 

});
```

css:

```
.activeLink {
    background-color: #31A7DF;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <a class="nav-link link dropdown-toggle text-white paddingRightButton h-100 noPaddingRightLeft" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="flatRoofingDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Flat Roofing
                        </a>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seemed to have resolved my issue

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        $('.link.activeLink').removeClass('activeLink')
    });

    $('.link').click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).hasClass('activeLink')) {
            $(this).removeClass('activeLink');
        } else {
            $('.link.activeLink').removeClass('activeLink')
            $(this).toggleClass('activeLink');
        }         
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use `.toggleClass()` Toggle class will look and see if it's there, and remove it if it is, and add it if it isn't. Your last case should look like this:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('activeLink');
}
```

The above code is *all* you need to check and toggle classes with jQuery. :)

Comment: Hey, ok so this works if i remove my second statement. however the link dont remove the class still upon click if i add this logic and dont remove anything. Something seems to be interfering with something else.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm sure we can fix it for you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the if-statement is not required at all.
According to jQuery documentation `toggleClass`already does the job for you. See [example here](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#example-0) it looks like that does what you try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to add the `hasClass` logic around `toggleClass()`, since that's what `toggleClass(className)` does for you.

- does the equivalent of `addClass(className)` if `className` isn't present
- does the equivalent of `removeClass(className)` if it is

Reference here: [api.jquery.com/toggleclass/](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

---

### Try this:

```html
<a class="link activeLink">link 1</a>
<a class="link">link 2</a>
```

```js
$('.link').click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('activeLink');
});

// link 1 clicked:
// <a class="link">link 1</a>

// link 2 clicked:
// <a class="link activeLink">link 2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword here is event propagation, so every click on the link is also a click on the document, as `.link` is a child of `document`.

The code below should do the trick. It toggles the class if the link is clicked, and it always removes the class if anything else but the link is clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#flatRoofingDropdown').click(function(event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('activeLink');
  });
  
  $(document).click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('#flatRoofingDropdown').length) {
    $('#flatRoofingDropdown').removeClass('activeLink');
  }
});

});
```

```css
.activeLink {
  background-color: #31A7DF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nav-link link dropdown-toggle text-white paddingRightButton h-100 noPaddingRightLeft" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="flatRoofingDropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  Flat Roofing
</a>
```